# Magento 2: Edit special price for all variants of configurable product at once

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, special-price

Is it possible to change the special price of all variants of configurable products at once?
Backend is very slow in Magento 2, so loading f.e. 10 simple products variants (which are associated with a configurable product) and apply the same special price / discount on all products is very frustrating.

Is there an extension / feature which updates the special price of the simple products in an easy / fast way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Magento's "Update Attributes" feature. Which allows you to change specific attributes on a bunch of products at the same time.

To use it simply filter the product list for your desired simple products and choose "Update attributes" from the dropdown list. Also see the following screenshot:

[image]

Then in the subsequent screen, check the "change" box for Special Price and enter your desired price.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly it does not update the prices in the frontend, though they are correctly applied in backend, in the different variants. I figured out, that I need to open the configured product and just save it (probably to trigger an index update?). Is this a bug?

Comment: This unfortunately seems to be a bug yes (I can't find a bug report on the github atm). Cache is not cleared properly when using the Update attributes feature. I've personally solved this by adding a plugin on Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Action\Attribute that clears the cache through beforeExecute. Another solution is to manually clear the cache of course.

Comment: Thank you again. Would it be possible that you share your code, which clears the cache as you described it?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://github.com/sduif/magento2-233040-update-atributes-cache (provided as-is)